# how can I connect surveyjs library to databse(Mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, surveyjs

using this example (Surveyjs Library) [Surveyjs-recat-quickstart](https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs_react_quickstart) I do not know how can I connect my Mysql database on this example, knowing that I wanted to add a score for each type of question (for example radio question (item1_score = 2, item2_score = 4 ...))

Answer (score 1):

You can check this repo - https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs-nodejs
Especially this file - https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs-nodejs/blob/master/mysqldbadapter.js

Comment: ` function getObjectFromStorage(tableName, callback) {

    db.query("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, function(err, result){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(result);
      var objects = {};
      (result || []).forEach(function(item) {
        objects[item.id] = item;
      });
      callback(objects);
    });
  }`

Comment: I can not retrieve the survey (the example defined in the code) with this code `getObjectFromStorage("surveys", function(objects) {
      logger.log({
        level: 'info',
        message: "callback getObjectFromStorage "+objects
      });
      if (Object.keys(objects).length > 0) {
        callback(objects);
      } else {
        callback(surveys);
      }
    });`

Comment: Probably it's better to ask exactly this question in mysql thread (and prepare a MRE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to illustrate your exact problem